# I tried to send email using php mail function but it doesn't happening?

Tags: php, html

I tried to send a mail using php mail(). But, it successfully executing the code but I am not receiving mail from my php script. I tried to change **php.ini** and **sendmail** files by looking all over the internt nothing is happening. I am using XAMPP and my application needs to be intranet based

```
<?php
   $to_email = "sampathatmuri31@gmail.com";
   $subject = "Simple Email Test via PHP";
   $body = "Hi, This is test email send by PHP Script";
   $headers = "From: urwithdreamracer@gmail.com";

   if ( mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
      echo("Email successfully sent to $to_email...");
   } else {
      echo("Email sending failed...");
   }
?>
```

my **php.ini** file

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path ="C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail().
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header=Off

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
;mail.log =
; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on Windows).
;mail.log = syslog
```

my **sendmail** file

```
; configuration for fake sendmail

; if this file doesn't exist, sendmail.exe will look for the settings in
; the registry, under HKLM\Software\Sendmail

[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=25

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=auto

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

;default_domain=mydomain.com

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

;debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=
auth_password=

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=
```

Comment: Hi, it is always best to copy/paste relevant things like those 2 file on github into your question. Then if you get rid of the github the question will not then be missing something relevant

Comment: sure, I pasted those two files in my question @RiggsFolly. Thank you foe the feedback.

Comment: Don't use `mail()`! There are a lot of problems you'll have to deal with (or fix with a ton of work). Use something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) instead.

Comment: Thank you @Aaron3219. Is it necessary to create a google XOAUTH2 when someone working on with PHPMailer ?.

Comment: @SampathAtmuri I don't think so. But you certainly can.